# excel automation using python

Tags: excel, automation

I am trying to write a function to read data from excel file using python. My function should read rows from excel sheet one at a time. Below is my code which will print 1st row.

```
import xlrd  
from xlrd import open_workbook, cellname  

book = open_workbook('./Excel/Book1.xls')  
def read_excel(sheetName):  
sheet = book.sheet_by_name(sheetName)  
row = sheet.nrows  
for i in range(1):  
    rows = sheet.row_values(i+1)  
    print(rows)
```

Comment: thanks in advance..

Comment: I don't know python ? but what you want sir?

Comment: I want to write a function which will  return one row at a time from excel sheet.

Answer (score 0):

```
file = r'd:\pythonTest.xlsx '
import xlrd 

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(file) 
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0) 

# For row 0 and column 0 
sheet.cell_value(0, 0) 

# Extracting number of columns 
print(sheet.ncols)
print(sheet.nrows)

print(sheet.row_values(1)) 

for i in range(sheet.nrows): 
    print(sheet.cell_value(i, 0), sheet.cell_value(i, 1))
```

Comment: I downloaded xlrd code and run it in python 3.6 and it is showing error. Can you pls provide the link to import xlrd

Comment: Try to use it in Anaconda

Comment: Thanks will check and let you know